# Определить тип сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Когда толпа была уже за дубовым кустарником в поле, где дул теплый ветер и пели жаворонки, от церкви отъехала плетеная тележка, запряженная серым мерином в яблоках.

Comment: @Yil, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Надо найти союз, определить его разряд, а потом и искомый тип.